# Google cloud load balancing and reverse DNS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, reverse-dns

I have a domain example.com pointing at a Google Cloud load balancer. Requests get served by one of several Compute Engines behind the load balancer.

The load balancer ip is 1.2.3.4

Now when I send email from email@example.com sometimes it gets black listed because the reverse lookup for 1.2.3.4 does not return example.com instead it returns 71.22.211.130.bc.googleusercontent.com

I know that I can set a PTR on the individual virtual machines behind the load balancer but I don't think this will solve the problem.

Is there a solution that will make 1.2.3.4 return example.com or another typical solution?

Comment: I would recommend to move this question to Serverfault, looks more suitable there.

Comment: I saw your comment on my previous answer.  If that is the case, PTR record is in Google Cloud's hands... I don't have a google cloud account to experiment it with,  it looks like as you mentioned you can create PTR for the VM, not on the load balancer which I agree that's not going to solve the problem.  You might want to ask Google Cloud support or Serverfault as Katie suggested.  I removed my answered which is not applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as of this writing, it is not possible to configure a PTR record for a load balancer.

You can only [add a PTR record](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-ptr-record) for a VM instance inside of Google Cloud, and this is done with a setting on the default network interface.